# I can't install i386 arch on ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: 14.04, wine, skype, 32-bit

I've the same problems with Trusty.

Can I receive the commands to resolve my problem ?

I can't install Skype, wine and all software with 386 libraries.(Always problems of depends).

I'm sorry for my English, I'm a beginner in that language.

For example for wine install :

```
bruno@bruno:~$
 sudo apt-get install wine
[sudo] password for bruno:



Reading Package Lists... Done Building Dependency Tree reading of
 information of state... Fact Some packages can not be installed. 
This may mean that you have asked the impossible, or, if you use the
 unstable distribution, that some packages have not yet been created 
or are not out of Incoming. 
The following information should help you to resolve the situation:

The following packages contain dependencies not satisfied: 
wine: Depends: wine1.6 but will not be installed 
E: impossible to correct the problems, bad packets are in mode 
"keep in the State".
```

And for skype :

```
bruno@bruno:~$ 

sudo apt-get build-dep -a i386 skype
Reading Package Lists... Done Building Dependency Tree
reading of information of state... Done 
The following packages contain dependencies not met:
libqtwebkit-dev:i386: Depends: libqtwebkit4:i386 (= 2.3.2-0Ubuntu7) but
 will not be installed 
E: to build dependencies for Skype can not be met.
```

Comment: Have you tried "dpkg --add-architecture i386" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: I've tried all that it was said, but nothing to do. Always the sames errors of depends.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried with aptitude and I've that :

`...The following packages have nonsatisfied dependences: libcgmanager0: Breakage: libcgmanager0: i386 (! = 0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1) but 0.24-0ubuntu7.5 must be installed. libcgmanager0: i386: Breakage: libcgmanager0 (! = 0.24-0ubuntu7.5) but 0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1 is installed. The following actions will make it possible to solve these dependences: To preserve the following packages in their current version: 1) libcgmanager0: i386 [Not installed] 2) libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid: i386 [Not installed] 3) libqt4-opengl: i386 [Not installed] 4) libqtwebkit4: i386 [Not installed] 5) libudev1: i386 [Not installed] 6) skype [Not installed]`

Than, I've made :

bruno@bruno: ~$ sudo aptitude libcgmanager0

`installation: i386 E: Impossible to obtain the /var/lib/dpkg/lock bolt - open (11: Resource temporarily nonavailable) E: Impossible to lock the repertoire of administration (/var/lib/dpkg/). It is possible that another process uses it. W: Impossible to lock the file hides: that is in general due to a simultaneous installation of packages with dpkg or another tool like APT. Opening in reading mode alone: NONE the modifications of the state of the packages which you will be able to make will be preserved. E: Impossible to obtain the /var/lib/dpkg/lock bolt - open (11: Resource temporarily nonavailable) E: Impossible to lock the repertoire of administration (/var/lib/dpkg/). It is possible that another process uses it.`